# I use System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) a lot in my app, I just migrated from Xamarin to Maui

Tags: xamarin, maui

As the title says, I use System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) a lot in my app. It is crucial, I just migrated my app over to Maui from Xamarin and now it is not locating those files. What name/part of the build/package needs to be changed to match so that it finds those files. My users are going to lose a LOT of data if I can't figure this out.

Thank you!

The application ID and title both match exactly, the default namespace IS different, but I figured it looked deeper than that. It obviously looks at something to determine which app it is.....I just need to know what and how to make it match.

Comment: If the new version is using the same bundle ID It should install over the old version and maintain the same relative file paths

Comment: It doesn't....so I noticed when I download the apk on my phone, and go to install it (with the previous version still installed) I get the update option as I normally do. However, when I click update, it says "App not installed as package appears to be invalid" - but if I uninstall that old version and just install the new one it installs and runs no problem, it just is going to a different path....

Comment: Add to question the old path, and the new path. Those environment variables return strings. What part of them is different?

Comment: /data/user/0/pp.chasemeade.proapp/files
/data/user/0/pp.chasemeade.proapp/files ------ These are the file paths returned........both exactly the same. Yet it is almost as if there are two separate instances of the same path. Old version of the app, the file exists, new version in Maui....files don't exist.

Comment: You said you had to delete the app to install the new one? That deletes all app data.

Comment: Nope. All of the data is still there, deleting an app does not delete those files. I can install the old version and all the files are still there, uninstall it install the new version, files don't exist. Install the old one again, files are there.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this was "Personal", which is equivalent to "MyDocuments".

Comment: I'm at a total loss.....I don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with "scoped storage". Was the old app built to target an API lower than 29? That's when scoped storage was introduced. I haven't found any explanation as to how an app could have same bundle id, yet not be considered "an update of the same app". AFAIK, it must be same bundle id, or the path would change. Submit a support ticket to Google. Until it looks like a valid update, you won't be able to see/access existing files in that "data" folder; they are "owned" by the original app. As a test, permission "All files access". Should be able to see. But don't publish with that.

Comment: Version numbers and signatures?

Comment: An update...so it is pretty strange, there must be more to the file path that is hidden even when displaying the file path. Moral of the story, same exact apk, I have a separate set of files when it is installed manually on my phone vs. the official update I released on the Play Store. Strange, but it works!